# how to read an array from file and assign it to variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

I am trying to read an array from file which I made earlier and then assign it to variable.
But now i ran into a problem. When i assigned that file content to variable, it became string instead of array.
how do i convert that back to an array ?

file.txt content:

> [(0, 0.2, ),(0, 0.1, ),(0.2, 0.2, ),(0.2, 0.2, ),(0.4, 0.2, ),]

my code:

```
valid_outputs = f=open("fileName.txt","r")
if(f.mode == 'r'):
    valid_outputs = f.read()
```

Comment: That's not an array, it's a Python `list` with `tuple` values. Not sure how you managed to produce that exact string however, as the Python representation would not include the trailing commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = None
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    x = eval(f.read())

print x
```

Comment: this one works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) on the string:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('[(0, 0.2, ),(0, 0.1, ),(0.2, 0.2, ),(0.2, 0.2, ),(0.4, 0.2, ),]')
[(0, 0.2), (0, 0.1), (0.2, 0.2), (0.2, 0.2), (0.4, 0.2)]
```

Comment: I updated the link to Python 3...  mostly to help search engines get the right one, but OP did explicitly tag Python-3

Comment: @SamMason: Good catch, thanks for doing that!

Answer (score 0):

Slightly convoluted, but without any packages:

```
>>> [tuple([float(i) for i in block.split(",")[:2]]) for block in valid_outputs.replace(")]", "").replace("[(", "").split("),(")]
[(0.0, 0.2), (0.0, 0.1), (0.2, 0.2), (0.2, 0.2), (0.4, 0.2)]
```